# Azure Functions Extension Bundle Version Issue for Local Development

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions

I have a Java 11 Azure Function with a queue trigger that works as expected when deployed to Azure and properly pulls messages off of the defined service bus topic.   However, running the same function *locally* does not work unless I rollback the version of the [Azure Functions binding extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-register).  If I don't revert the version back, the function starts locally but never pulls messages off the service bus topic.

The variable is the `host.json` file in the project that defines the extension bundle version.  For the function deployed to Azure, the following `host.json` file is used which is configured for the latest version of the extension bundle:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.3.0, 4.0.0)"
  }
}
```

The version that works locally is this:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  }
}
```

The Azure function itself doesn't do anything special.  When setting a breakpoint in the function, it is never called if I don't revert the Extension Bundle version back to the 2/3 version.

```
 public class QueueTrigger {

  private DatabaseProvider database;

  @FunctionName(Constants.FunctionNames.RUN_CHANGE_HISTORY_TRIGGER)
  public void run(
    @ServiceBusTopicTrigger(name = "msg",
      topicName = "%SERVICE_BUS_TOPIC_NAME%",
      subscriptionName = "%SERVICE_BUS_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME%",
      connection = "ServiceBusConnection") String message,
    final ExecutionContext context) {

    Logger logger = context.getLogger();

    try {
      logger.log(Level.INFO, String.format("Queue Trigger START (%s)", message));

      database = new CosmosDatabaseProvider(logger);

      ChangeHistoryService service = new ChangeHistoryService(database, logger);
      service.processChanges(message);

      this.database.close();

      logger.log(Level.INFO, "Queue Trigger DONE");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
      logger.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage());
      throw new ServiceResponseException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
  }
}
```

I have the [Azure Function Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Cwindows%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash%2Ckeda) v4.0.3971 (latest version) installed on my PC, as do the rest of my team members that all have this same issue.

What am I missing in my local environment that is preventing the latest version of the extension bundle from working?

Comment: I'm using the same with a queue instead of a topic, these are the commands i used to install the core tools `brew tap azure/functions
brew install azure-functions-core-tools@3
# if upgrading on a machine that has 2.x installed
brew link --overwrite azure-functions-core-tools@3

#Install extensions
func extensions install`

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce the issue by following steps:

1. Created Azure Functions (***Stack: Java***) in VS Code with Queue Trigger example.
2. By default, version is `3.*, 4.0.0` in ***host.json*** and the messages are pulling successfully.

[image]

After downgrading to version `2.*, 3.0.0` of azure functions extension bundles in ***host.json***, the messages are pulling off successfully.

[image]

When running the azure functions (java), the runtime takes latest version mentioned in the `host.json` automatically and with which version it is running can be seen in the output terminal when in it is running.

Comment: Thank you for researching this.  The issue I have is that your Step 2 isn't working for me when debugging a local version of the Azure Function and I'm not sure why.  The Function starts but never pulls messages of the configured service bus topic with the "[3.3.0, 4.0.0)" version.

Comment: Could you please provide your function code and host.json code!

Comment: The complete host.json is already in the original post.  I just added the function code, which is largely irrelevant as the code isn't even hit when using the "[3.3.0, 4.0.0)" version in the host.json file in local development.

Comment: How did you downgrade? When I try to run my function is using Core Tools Version:       4.0.5198. I need it to run v3 so I changed my host.json to     "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
 however it's still running 4.0....