# How to use self hosted ExtensionBundle

Tags: azure, azure-functions

When working locally, how can one direct azure-core-tools to download "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle" from a self hosted endpoint instead of "https://functionscdn.azureedge.net/public/ExtensionBundles/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle/index.json"?

In a enterprise environment, internet proxy often bock access to the internet and artefact have to instead of hosted on the intranet.

Comment: [Custom Extension Bundle](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-extension-bundles/wiki/Custom-Extension-Bundle), [Latest bundle 3.5.0 cannot be used as not appearing in https://functionscdn.azureedge.net/public/ExtensionBundles/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle/index.json](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-extension-bundles/issues/140), and [Extension Bundles v2.8.5 and v3.5.0 have been abandoned](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-extension-bundles/issues/141)

Comment: [Azure Functions Extension Bundle Version Issue for Local Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70452834/azure-functions-extension-bundle-version-issue-for-local-development)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @DeepDave-MT comment I was able to figure it out.

Upload the extension bundles and index.json somewhere following strict paths:

`/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle/<version>/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle.<version>.zip` (can be downloaded from https://functionscdn.azureedge.net/public/ExtensionBundles/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle/2.13.0/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle.2.13.0.zip)

`/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle/index.json` (you use that file https://functionscdn.azureedge.net/public/ExtensionBundles/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle/index.json)

Set the an environment variable before starting az function core tools `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSIONBUNDLE_SOURCE_URI=https://example.net/some/path/`

Az core tools will first fetch the index.json, checking the versions listed there and then downloading the zip.