# Could not load type Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ParameterBindingData

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I am currently developing an Azure Function in VS Code. I am encountering an error that has already been reported in this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/34467). In full, the error reads: `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ParameterBindingData' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs, Version=3.0.34.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=****'. Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')`

One of the suggested solutions is to downgrade the package version of the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage`. However, I do not know how to downgrade a package from an extension bundle. In my local development environment, I'm using the following default `host.json` configuration:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.15.0, 4.0.0)"
  }
}
```

I already tried multiple version ranges, each lead to the same error.
Since I'm not familiar with `.NET`, I would appreciate any help or advice on how to downgrade the package to resolve this issue. Thank you.

**Additional information:**
I am developing an EventHub Triggered Function locally using the test trigger:

```
@app.function_name(name="EventHubTrigger1")
@app.event_hub_message_trigger(arg_name="myhub", event_hub_name="samples-workitems",
                               connection="") 

def test_function(myhub: func.EventHubEvent):
    logging.info('Python EventHub trigger processed an event: %s',
                myhub.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
```

The `local.settings.json` is as follows:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"
  }
}
```

*Update:*
Another way to solve this issue was to reinstall/ update the azure function core tools using these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install azure-functions-core-tools-4
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Refer my answer in this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76170250/how-to-downgrade-microsoft-azure-webjobs-extensions-storage-to-version-5-0-1/76170550#76170550) to resolve the similar error code.
>
> Refer the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73645163/unable-to-upgrade-azure-functions-core-tools-exception-cannot-create-instance) by Jon koeter and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73034959/microsoft-azure-webjobs-extensions-http-could-not-load-file-or-assembly) by Victoria Berra
>
> ***Make sure you delete these 2 folders from your Local machine that might be conflicting when you run the Azure Function locally:-***
>
> [image]

After deleting these 2 folders, Make sure you delete Azure Function Core tools, you can get the path to your Azure Function Core tools from Environment variable from below settings in your local machine:-

[image]

***Visit > C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\ and then delete the Azure Functions Core Tools folder.***

[image]

> Now, Install Azure Function core tools from this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4,windows,csharp,portal,bash#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools) again and then create and run the Azure Function event grid trigger.

***I installed Azure Function Core tools again by following the link above and Created one Azure Event grid trigger locally the Trigger ran successfully like below:-***

[image]

Comment: In the end deleting the bundle worked with the caveat that on WSL with network restrictions we have to download and unzip the bundle from [here](https://functionscdn.azureedge.net/public/ExtensionBundles/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle/2.13.0/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle.2.13.0.zip) as answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72704047/how-to-use-self-hosted-extensionbundle). @SiddheshDesai, for some reasons your images are not rendering. You should fix it to make it easier to understand for future readers.

Comment: I uninstalled the tools first, then deleted the directories, followed by removing the path in the environment. Followed by a fresh install. Which then worked.

Answer (score 7):

This problem was resolved by updating the version range to:

`"version": "[3.3.0, 3.9.0)"`

Answer (score 4):

I have the same error in Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle version 3.21.0.
Solution: Modify the `version` in host.json to `"version": "[3.*, 3.9.0)"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the issue on MAC, I could make it run with following host.json file

```
 "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.3.0, 4.0.0)"
  },
```

And additionally needed to reinstall azure-functions-core-tools

```
brew uninstall azure/functions/azure-functions-core-tools
brew uninstall azure/functions/azure-functions-core-tools@4
brew install azure/functions/azure-functions-core-tools@4
```

Comment: do you have an apple silicon?